# How to make the sh script return an error code from the executed command?

Tags: shell, sh

I wrote a simple script which will prompt pppd to work. I have read in the pppd documentation that it can return an exit code in the range 1-20. I would like my script to return the value of pppd if it is not 0. I tried this way but unfortunately it failed.

myscript.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh

exec pppd call ${@:-provider}
if [ $? !-eq 0 ]
then
  exit $?
fi
```

How could i get the exit code from pppd?

Comment: There you can't. `exec` isn't simply a call to a utility, `exec` replaces the current shell with a new one for `pppd call` -- it never returns. You could do `if !pppd call ${@:-provider}; then exit X; fi;` if you just wanted to have the current shell wait for the `pppd` script to finish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do:

```
#!/bin/sh

pppd call "${@:-provider}" || exit
...
```

or

```
if pppd call "${@:-provider}"; then : ; else exit; fi
```

If `pppd` fails, the script will exit and the value it returns will be that returned by pppd.  (You could explicitly write `exit $?`, but that is the default value returned by exit when no argument is given and is not necessary.) If `pppd` succeeds, the script will continue.

The problem with your script (other than the ill-advised usage of `exec`, which I will mostly ignore) is that calling `[ $? -ne 0 ]` resets `$?`.  You could re-write your script as:

```
#!/bin/sh

pppd call "${@:-provider}"
save_val=$?
if ! [ $save_val -eq 0 ]
then
  exit $save_val
fi
```

but that seems excessively verbose.

Note that in your original script, you would get an error on the line `if [ $? !-eq 0 ]`, since `!-eq` is not a valid operator. However, you never see that error because your early invocation of `exec` makes it so that line is never executed.